# Uploading application to google play

Tags: android

I am trying to upload an updated version of my application (.apk) in google play. The apk is only 1.5mb in size, but it has been uploading for the past 20 minutes, and the progress bar has not moved. Any ideas? I have tried 3 times.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could just be either a problem on your Internet Connection or a problem on Google's servers.

Try to disconnect and reconnect or to change browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restarting your computer. If nothing works you may want to consider the possibility that Google Play is currently experiencing network issues with uploading new application files and possibly other things.